# Error: mysql55-libs conflicts with mysql-libs while trying to upgrade to mysql5.5 from 5.1 on centos6.3

Tags: mysql

Error: mysql55-libs conflicts with mysql-libs while trying to upgrade to mysql5.5 from 5.1 on centos6.3
Tried with remi repo and it got installed but unable to see the mysqld service

Could u pls help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog that describes the steps you need:

http://blog.iphoting.com/blog/2012/06/19/upgrading-to-mysql-5-dot-5-on-centos-6/

Basically, you have to remove the `mysql-libs` 5.1 package, and then install the mysql55-libs package.  Note this may conflict with any other packages that are depending on mysql-libs, so you may have to disable dependency checking for the erase and the upgrade.

The upgraded package should have *provides* set so that it satisfies other package dependencies.

But don't quote me -- if I were you, I'd test the upgrade procedure on a VM first.